# Setting up Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A point mass m in the (x, y)–plane is subject to a constant
force pulling it directly down in the direction of the negative y–axis (and no
other forces). Express this as a pair of ODEs for x and for y.

I need help setting this ODE up. Do I need to set up 2 separate ODEs? and for x wouldn't there be no change at all if the force is pulling it directly down?